# Add a form with POST method on a SharePoint 2010 page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

The HTML I got asked to add to a page is:

```
<div>
  <div> Click below to enter</div>
  <form id="formID" method=POST action="http://www.someWebsite.com">
    <input type="submit" name="do_login" value="Log in" />
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="someUsername" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="somePassword" />
  </form>
</div>
```

I know I can't add a form like that because there is already on that SharePoint created, I had a look at http://www.sharepointboris.net/2008/09/making-post-and-get-forms-from-sharepoints-pages/ but when I follow the example and save SharePoint still strips out most of the code so how can I achieve what I want in another way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For our SharePoint 2007 installation, I created a quiz web part.  Basically, it pulls questions and answers from a list, but the actual questions are presented and submitted using a form with POST variables.  It's probably much more complex and in-depth than you're looking to go, but I made a custom web part to present the form, read the post variables, and execute associated functions.  The big plus to using a custom web part is that you're able to put in nearly any content you want, since you're coding it in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to create a custom .aspx page (not through the sharepoint gui) with the code I posted in my question, uploaded the page to a library and then linked to it via a page viewer web part

Answer (score -1):

You can get the form to work as normal if you remove the  tags and place the form control inside a div like so:

```
<div>
<div> Click below to enter</div>
<div id="formID" method=POST action="http://www.someWebsite.com">
<input type="submit" name="do_login" value="Log in" />
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="someUsername" />
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="somePassword" />
</div>
</div>
```

This way sharepoint will accept everything inside the div tags. In a asp.net when you create a page in sharepoint, the whole page is containied withing a form that why sharepoint does not allow you to use another form within it.

Hope this helps